# Multiple Texmaker windows?

Tags: texmaker, editors, mac

In OS-X, is there a way to open multiple windows of TeXmaker, each for viewing and editing different (or same) files?

Comment: Not that I know of. All you have is tabs.

Comment: You can switch between [`source viewer`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6hDE-psV4Q)--> comparing with `other.tex` and `pdf viewer`--> view output of `main.tex`.

Comment: @texenthusiast What do you mean?

Comment: @Jubobs I too agree with you,hence posted the alternative

Comment: As posted in other answers/comments: maybe switching over to another editor maybe a choice?  Here is a comparison of different [TeX editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).  There is also a page on TeX.SE which lists a [lot of editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Answer (score 9):

###Short answer: `texmaker -n`
In recent versions (4.2+) it should be possible to launch a new instance of `texmaker` using the option `-n`.
E.g. from command-line

```
texmaker -n whatever.tex
```

#### The whole story

From the source files package, `./utilities/CHANGELOG.txt` we can read

> 

### version 1.7.1 -> 1.8:
texmaker can now be only started once per user : inverse search will no  more launch a new instance of texmaker

> version 4.1.1 -> 4.2 :
> with the new option "-n" for the command line, a new instance of Texmaker can be launched (will break the synchronization with the pdf viewers and others feautures)

#### The Puzzle / Documentation bug [?]

On some (non official)  man pages of TexMaker<sup>[[1](http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/texmaker/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38)],[[2](http://fossies.org/linux/texmaker/doc/usermanual_en.html)]</sup> I found, in the section 4.9, the syntax:

> 

texmaker file [-master] [-line xx] [-insert foo] [-n]

> ...
> With the `-n` option a new instance of Texmaker is launched (will break synchronization with the PDF viewers).

But in the same section of the manual on the official site <sup>[[3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html)]</sup> was reported a different syntax:

```
texmaker file [-master] [-line xx] [-insert foo]
```

BTW in the documentation files of the source package <sup>[[4](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)]</sup> downloadable from the official page,  the `-n` option is listed in the manual... unfortunately I had not the opportunity to compile or to install the last version, but it should work for each system.

#### Updates

- In the 5.1.2 version we read again from the official site <sup>[[3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html)]</sup>:

> With the "-n" option a new instance of Texmaker is launched (will break synchronization with the pdf viewers).

- I was using the 5.0.2 version under Ubuntu.
  Although not reported by man, the `-n` option opened a new instance of `texmaker`.

Answer (score 2):

My best alternative is to use another tex editor (such as the basic texWorks which comes with the mikTex download)

**EDIT**
As mentioned since OS-X does not use miktek another solution is to download, install, and use TeXstudio to view two documents at once. Again it's a work around but it's simple and quick.

http://www.texstudio.org/

Comment: This doesn't help. The OP is working on OS-X, which doesn't support the Windows-only MiKTeX.

Comment: @Werner As mentioned in the edit texStudio is another option. Thanks for the heads up on miktek and OS-X.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but just made my comment to answer to keep the thread answered:

I don't think Multiple Texmaker windows could be opened(as suggested by Jubobs) because all `.tex` files are opened inside one window only with drop down menu selection of each of them. Hence an alternative approach is to switch between [source viewer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6hDE-psV4Q)--> comparing with other`.tex` and pdf viewer--> view output of `main.tex`